# Difference between equations of sphere and hyperboloid

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

The simplest form for the equation of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is:

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$$

where $r$ is the sphere radius. This substantially is the Pythagorean Theorem, applied to the triangle whose squared sides are

- $a^2 = x^2 + y^2$
- $z^2$

$r^2$ is the square of the resulting hypotenuse.

Conversely, the simplest form for the equation of a hyperboloid is:

$$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = k^2$$

where $k$ is a real fixed number.

If the equation of a sphere represents the Pythagorean Theorem, what does instead the equation of a hyperboloid represent? Is there any other intuitive idea behind it?

Due to the minus sign, it can't be the Pythagorean Theorem again, unless the length $z$ is considered as pure imaginary.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. The shape of a hyperboloid depends on whether it's of one sheet or of two sheets. You can check out the wiki for some visuals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid. The $k^2$ suggests that you're dealing with one sheet.

Comment: If you fix $z$ and write it like

$$x^2 +y^2 =k^2 +z^2 $$

you can think of it like this: at each value of $z$ draw a circle of radius $\sqrt{k^2+z^2}$ centered at the origin.

Comment: As a note, interestingly enough the idea that an hyperboloid turns into a sphere if you take the last coordinate to be purely imaginary is used in physics under the name of Wick rotation to go back and forth between Minkowski and Euclidean space

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a geometric/intuitive interpretation of a hyperboloid. For any hyperboloid, there exist points $A$ and $B$ (the foci of the hyperboloid) such that the hyperboloid is the locus of points satisfying $|AP - BP| = c$ for some constant $c$. You can simply see the hyperboloid as a rotation of a hyperbola around its axis. This also satisfies reflective properties analogous to the hyperbola. For more information, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Comment: Really? What are the foci of the hyperboloid in the question, then? It’s obtained by rotating a rectangular hyperbola about its _conjugate_ axis. Even a hyperboloid of two sheets such as $x^2-2y^2-3z^2=1$ fails to have foci. There are many other hyperboloids besides those that are rotations of a hyperbola about its transverse axis.